# Ag-grid : Color a cell in a row without using the Cell Styles property in column definitions

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

```
[{
    "uniqueIdentifier": "12345",
    "identifier": "UJHU",
    "latitude": 33.68131385650486,
    "longitude": -83.36814721580595,
    "cycle": "1"
    "speedLimit": "255"
    "customerCode": "Standard",
    "altitude" : 12345
    "modifiedKeys": [
      "speedLimit",
      "altitude"
    ]
  },
   {
    "uniqueIdentifier": "13434",
    "identifier": "UJHU",
    "latitude": 93.68131385650486,
    "longitude": -33.36814721580595,
    "cycle": "2"
    "speedLimit": "255"
    "customerCode": "Standard",
    "altitude" : 12345
    "modifiedKeys": [
      "cycle",
      "latitude"
    ]
  }]
```

The above Json is feed to Ag-grid. Requirement is to color the cells if it belongs to the column names present under  `modifiedKeys` in the above Json.

I dont want to define it using the Cell Class Rules as given [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-styles/) because I have hundreds of columns in my grid.
I want to use something like `rowClassRules` which can be passed as an input to the Ag-grid. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Cell Style rules are the way to go. If you have hundreds of columns, and don't want to repeat the duplicate `cellStyle` function, add this function as a default to the column definitions.

Use this default column def:

```
defaultColDef = {
    cellStyle: function(params) {
        console.log(params);
        if (params.node.data.modifiedKeys.some(x => x == params.colDef.field)) {
          //mark police cells as red
          return { backgroundColor: "green" };
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      }
  }
```

And pass it to your grid like so:

```
<ag-grid-angular 
    style="width: 500px; height: 200px;" 
    class="ag-theme-alpine"
    [rowData]="rowData" 
    [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-fby25z) is a StackBlitz demonstration.

Comment: Perfect ..!! That's what I was looking for . I was not  aware of DefaultColDef property. Thanks for the working example.